# Python List Comprehension: Using "if" Statement on Result of the Comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Can you filter a list comprehension based on the **result** of the transformation in the comprehension?

For example, suppose you want to strip each string in a list, and remove strings that are just whitespace. I could easily do the following:

```
filter(None, [x.strip() for x in str_list])
```

But that iterates over the list twice. Alternatively you could do the following:

```
[x.strip() for x in str_list if x.strip()]
```

But that implementation performs `strip` twice. I could also use a generator:

```
for x in str_list:
   x = x.strip()
   if x:
      yield x
```

But now that's a bunch of lines of code. Is there any way of doing the above (1) only iterating once; (2) only performing the transformation once; and (3) in a single list comprehension? The example above is a toy example, but I'd like to do this with longer lists and non-trivial transforms.

**Update:** I'm using Python 2.7.X, and prefer answers in that, but if Python 3 has some new features that make this easy, I'd be happy to learn about them as well.

Comment: Sadly not. The closest I can think of is double wrapping it - `[x for x in (y.strip() for y in str_list) if x]` Technically it's going over the list twice - but at least because the inside is using a generator, it won't use as much extra memory.

Comment: What version of Python? That is very important here.

Comment: @MadPhysicist good point, see update

Comment: Just write a for-loop and assign to a temporary variable. That would be the *Pythonic* way of doing it. Writing a couple of extra lines of code won't kill you. Relying on nesting generator expressions and other work-arounds is the opposite of elegant, IMO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't pass a list to `filter`, pass a generator expression, and it will only be iterated once:

```
filter(None, (x.strip() for x in str_list))
```

This is exactly the same idea as using a nested generator like

```
[y for y in (x.strip() for x in str_list) if y]
```

Both cases rely on the lazy evaluation of generators: each element of `str_list` will be processed exactly once, when the corresponding output element is created. No intermediate lists will be made.

The comprehension approach is nice for small one-shot transformations like these. Even the simple example here, which filters after the transformation, is pushing the limits of readability in my opinion. With any non-trivial sequence of transformations and filters, I would recommend using a `for` loop.

Comment: I always thought that `filter(None, iterable)` removes `None` elements. Now I learned that it removes every falsey element.

Answer (score 2):

Why not nest the comprehensions?

```
result = (x for x in (y.strip() for y in str_list) if len(x))
```

The inner `()` makes a generator that is just the stripped versions of strings in `str_list`. The outer `()` makes a second generator that consumes the first and produces only the non-empty elements. You traverse the list only once and strip each string only once.